# what does the "it" keyword do in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm following the rails3tutorial and I don't understand the meaning of the "it" keyword when doing some testing as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'new'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'new'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'new'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Sign up")
    end
  end
end
```

code fragment comes from: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top listing 5.26

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not a Ruby keyword, it's part of the [Rspec framework](http://rspec.info/).

`it` contains the code examples that illustrate the facet of behavior being 
defined. It is comprised of two main parts: the description string and 
the code example, in the do/end block.

Answer (score 22):

What I think the other answers could make more explicit, and what may be what initially confused you, is that `it` breaks most of the usual conventions for method naming (nothing about the method describes what it does, for example) in order to make the code as a whole read as a sort of sentence.

So rather than just creating a set of tests, the library is trying to encourage you to *describe* your application through tests in a way that resembles a human-readable specification.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a keyword. It's just a method provided by [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) used to describe spec samples. See [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it) for further explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In a general unit testing sense, **we use describe to describe the behavior of a class**:

```
describe Hash do

end
```

**Tests are written using the it block**. Here’s an example of how you might write a spec for the Hash class:

```
describe Hash do
  it "should return a blank instance" do
    Hash.new.should == {}
  end
end
```

For more help use it

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-rspec

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `it` is not a keyword.

That being said, a lot of words that appear to be keywords aren't keywords. For example, `puts` looks like a keyword, but it's merely a method in the `Kernel` module.